# jpa:repository is not recognized

Tags: java, spring, jpa, configuration, repository

I created a spring mvc project with annotation in order to test JpaRepository
Here is my Repository

```
package com.mvc.employeeManagement.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.mvc.employeeManagement.model.Employee;
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends  JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
}
```

and I keep getting this error when adding the repository tag

```
< jpa:repositories base-package="com.mvc.employeeManagement.repository" />
```

detected error

```
Error occured processing XML 'null'. See Error Log for more details applicationContext.xml  /EmployeManagementSystem/src/main/resources line 29 Spring Beans Problem
```

caused by

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor`

Thanks in advance

@Jason

Here is the detailed error

```
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/D:/Mega/workspaceJava/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/EmployeManagementSystem/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.findDescriptor(ReactiveWrappers.java:281)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isNoValueType(ReactiveWrappers.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isWrapper(ReactiveWrappers.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.supports(ReactiveWrappers.java:158)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.usesReactiveType(ReactiveWrappers.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.isReactiveRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.useRepositoryConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:365)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    ... 54 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at** org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're missing this dependency.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/

Comment: alright then, try this; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/

Comment: Should I use the same spring version 

this is the current one I am using :4.3.7.RELEASE ???

Comment: Then use 4.3.7 of spring-core.

Comment: What version of spring-core are you using?

Comment: this is the tag behind the error, it is in  applicationContext.xml content :
     
 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mvc.employeeManagement.repository"/>
 
the error says that :
Error occured processing XML 'Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation'

Comment: Show the entire exception, not a portion of it.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/D:/Mega/workspaceJava/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/EmployeManagementSystem/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor
 at ....

Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor